# Find the closest object from your position on a proper way QT c++

Tags: c++, qt, path-finding

I'm trying to find the closest Healthpacks or enemy from a player's position. I have wrote this like:

```
for(auto &hp : model->getAllHealthPacks()){
    if(!hp->getUsed()){
        int x = hp->getXPos();
        int y = hp->getYPos();
        int q = (x*x)+(y*y);
        if(q < smallest){
            smallest = z;
            hpfound = hp;
            foundAHp++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I was wondering, this is actually not proper. Are there better and profesional way's to improve my code? (Lambda,...)?

Comment: You may be interested to know that there is an actual [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site, which is probably a better place for this type of question.

Answer (score 1):

The code in general is not bad, but there is some room for improvement. First, you could make the variable hp a constant since you are not modifying its contents.

You could also create a class to store the coordinates in a single object like this

```
class Coordinate{
    std::pair<int,int> coords;
...
};
```

The final code could look like this:

```
for(const auto &hp : model->getAllHealthPacks()){
    if(!hp->getUsed()){
        Coordinate coord(hp->getCoord());
        int q = coord.getX()*coord.getX()+coord.getY()*coord.getY();
        if(q < smallest){
            smallest = z;
            hpfound = hp;
            foundAHp++;
        }
    }
}
```

You should also rename q to something more clear for future reference.